# The function (.).(.) in haskell

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming

I am trying to find the type of `(.).(.)` in Haskell, manually.

My attempt was the following:

```
(.).(.) = \x -> (.).(.) x

(.)     :: (     b   ->             c         )  ->  ((     a    ->           b        ) -> (a -> c))
(.)     :: (d -> e)  ->  ((f -> d) -> (g -> e))
(.)     ::                                              (h -> i) -> (j -> h) -> (h -> k)

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
b ~ (d -> e) ~ (j -> h) -> (h -> k)
c ~ ((f -> d) -> (g -> e))
a ~ (h -> i)
d ~ h
e ~ i                 

so (a->c)~     (h->i) -> ((f -> h) -> (g -> i))
```

What is wrong in my way of thinking? The actual type is

```
(.).(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a1 -> a2 -> b) -> a1 -> a2 -> c
```

Comment: Aha, the boob operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at the equivalent `(.) (.) (.)`

The first dot type:
`(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`

Second:
`(e -> f) -> (d -> e) -> d -> f`

Hence:

`b` is the same as `e -> f`

`c` is the same as `(d -> e) -> d -> f`

Third:
`(h -> i) -> (g -> h) -> g -> i`

Hence:

`a` is the same as `h -> i`

`b` is the same as `(g -> h) -> g -> i`

`e -> f` is `(g -> h) -> g -> i`

`e` is `g -> h`

`f` is `g -> i`

Since `(.) (.) (.) :: a -> c` from the first dot type, we have:

`a -> c` is `(h -> i) -> (d -> e) -> d -> f`

substituting `e` and `f`:
`(h -> i) -> (d -> g -> h) -> d -> g -> I`

Answering your question, I think that what is wrong with your thinking are last two lines e.g.:

`d ~ h`,
`e ~ i`

Answer (score 2):

Your derivation should have been :

```
(.).(.) = (.) (.) (.)

(.) :: (   b      ->           c          )  ->  (   a      ->           b          ) -> (a -> c) 
(.) ::  (d -> e)  ->  (f -> d) -> (g -> e)   -- WRONG
(.) ::                                            (h -> i)  ->  (j -> h) -> (h -> k)  -- WRONG
(.) ::  (d -> e)  ->  (f -> d) -> (f -> e)   -- correct
(.) ::                                            (h -> i)  ->  (j -> h) -> (j -> i)  -- correct
```

Thus the overall type is

```
(.) (.) (.) ::   a    ->                c                   ,   b ~ b
            ~  (h->i) ->  (f ->   d   ) -> (f ->   e   )    ,   (j -> h) -> (j -> i) ~ 
                                                               (   d     ->    e    )
             --------------------------------------------
               (h->i) ->  (f -> j -> h) -> (f -> j -> i)
```

Or,

```
               (                     h             -> i) 
                      ->  (f -> j -> h)
             --------------------------------------------
                                        -> (f -> j -> i)
```

---

The types of such composition chains are often easier to follow with `(>>>) = flip (.)`:

```
(.) . (.) = comp2  .  comp1
          = comp1 >>> comp2    where   comp1 = (.) ; comp2 = (.)

(>>>)    ::   (  a    ->         b         ) -> 
                        (        b           ->         c         )  ->  (a -> c)
comp1    ::    (e->f) -> ((d->e) -> (d->f))
comp2    ::              (  h    ->   i   )  -> ((g->h) -> (g->i))
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
               (e->f)                        -> ((g->h) -> (g->i))
                         h~(d->e)   i~(d->f)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
               (e->f) -> (g->d->e) -> (g->d->f)
```

Thus, again,

```
((.) . (.)) :: (c->r) -> (a->b->c) -> (a->b->r)
((.) . (.)) f g a b = f (g a b)
```

Indeed,

```
((.) . (.)) f g a b = ((.) . (.)) f  g  a  b
                    =  (.) ( (.)  f) g  a  b
                    =      ((f .)  . g) a  b     -- NB
                    =       (f .)  ( g  a) b
                    =       (f .     g  a) b

                    =        f (     g  a  b)
```

NB:

- [Why function composition sometimes requires two "." 's to combine two functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57431487/why-function-composition-sometimes-requires-two-s-to-combine-two-functions)

---

You can also verify that

```
((.) . (.) . (.)) :: (d->r) -> (a->b->c->d) -> (a->b->c->r)
((.) . (.) . (.)) f g a b c = f (g a b c)
```

Why? `(.)` is `fmap` for functions, and so we can re-write the above as

```
(fmap . fmap . fmap) f g a b c =
   fmap (fmap (fmap f)) g a b c =
   (do { x <- g ; return $ fmap (fmap f) x }) a b c =
   (do { x <- g ; return $ do { y <- x ; return $ fmap f y } }) a b c =
   (do { x <- g ; return $ do { y <- x ; return $ do { z <- y ; return $ f z } } }) a b c =
   let x=g a in (const $ do { y <- x ; return $ do { z <- y ; return $ f z } }) a b c =
   let x=g a in (do { y <- x ; return $ do { z <- y ; return $ f z } }) b c =
   let x=g a in let y=x b in (const $ do { z <- y ; return $ f z }) b c =
   let x=g a in let y=x b in (do { z <- y ; return $ f z }) c =
   let x=g a in let y=x b in let z=y c in const (f z) c =
   let x=g a in let y=x b in f (y c) =
   let x=g a in f (x b c) =
   f (g a b c)
```

This obviously works for any number of the chained compositions of `fmap`s that way.

Answer (score 1):

The simple definition of compose is:

```
compose f h x = f (h x)
```

and its type:

```
compose :: (t1 -> t2) -> (t3 -> t1) -> t3 -> t2
```

the type variable name changes because I defined manually. So, if you want to compose the compose function, you will need an extra argument, because compose takes a function that takes one argument, so, compose of compose will need an extra argument. The definition of compose of compose could be simple as:

```
composeOfCompose f h x y = f (h x y)
```

and its type, as you could figure is:

```
composeOfCompose :: (t1 -> t2) -> (t3 -> t4 -> t1) -> t3 -> t4 -> t2
```

why is that? well, follow the application of functions:

```
x :: t3
y :: t4
h :: t3 -> t4 -> t1
f :: t1 -> t2
composeOfCompose f h :: t3 -> t4 -> t2
```

if you think it like this is a little simpler, I guess, at least for me.

To add a little more info about it with the question in the comment of D. W.:

```
compose :: (t1 -> t2) -> (t3 -> t1) -> t3 -> t2
compose f h x = f (h x)

composeOfCompose :: (t1 -> t2) -> (t4 -> t5 -> t1) -> t4 -> t5 -> t2
composeOfCompose  = compose compose compose
```

If the first compose is `compose'` and the second compose is `compose''`

```
compose' (f' :: (t1 -> t2)) 
         (h' :: (**t3** -> t1)) (x' :: **t3**) = f' (h' x')
```

and the second should have:

```
compose'' (f'' :: (t4 -> t5))
          (h'' :: (t6 -> t4)) (x'' :: t6) = f'' (h'' x'')
```

so...

```
**t3** ~ (t4 -> t5)
meaning h :: t4 -> t5 -> t1
```

translating in place, the middle compose::

```
compose f h x = f :: t1 -> t2
                (h :: t4 -> t5 -> t1)
                    (x :: t4 -> t5)) :: t1
```

A simple example:

```
:t (.) . (.)
(.) . (.) :: (b -> c) -> (a1 -> a2 -> b) -> a1 -> a2 -> c
```

lets create a function for that:

```
composeOfCompose  = (.) . (.)

data A1 = A | B deriving Show
data A2 = C | D deriving Show
data B  = E | F deriving Show
data C  = G | H deriving Show

transform :: A1 -> A2 -> B
transform A C = E
transform B C = E
transform _ _ = F

finalTrans :: B -> C
finalTrans E = G
finalTrans F = H

main = do
  putStrLn $ show $ (composeOfCompose finalTrans transform) A D

$> H
```